# How do you match \'

Tags: perl, backslash

I need a regex to match **\'** <---- literally backslash apostrophe.

```
my $line = '\'this';
$line =~ s/(\o{134})(\o{047})/\\\\'/g;
$line =~ s/\\'/\\\\'/g;
$line =~ s/[\\][']/\\\\'/g;
printf('%s',$line);
print "\n";
```

All I get out of this is

```
'this
```

When what I want is

```
\\'this
```

This occurs whether the string is declared using `'` or `"`. This was a test script for tracking down a file parsing bug. I wanted to confirm that the regex was working as expected.

I don't know if when the backslash apostrophe is parsed by the regex it is not treated as 2 characters, but is instead treated as an escaped apostrophe.

Either way. what is the best way to match `\'` and print out `\\'`? I don't want to escape any other back slashes or apostrophes and I can't change the text I am parsing, just the way it is handled and outputted.

Comment: The code `my $line = "\'this";` will be interpolated to hold the string `'this`, perhaps you intended to write `my $line = "\\'this'`. Then substitution `$line =~ s/\\'/\\\\'/g;` will do what you have intended.

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish in the end, there is almost certainly an `escape` sub somewhere that will accomplish this.

Comment: `'\'this'` still evaluates to `'this`.  `q|\'this|` gives you `\'this`. Check before and after the substitution for better debugging experience.

Comment: thanks @clamp. Yes, I am aware that `'\'this'` evaluates to `'this`. That is why I was asking the question. I edited the question because the evaluation of `"\'this"` is more obvious. But in light of your comment I have edited again to make it super clear.

Comment: If you find yourself in escaping hell and aren't sure how a special character will be interpreted, write it as a hex code. \ -> `\x5C`, etc.  Verify the variable contents by printing it with `B::perlstring()`.

Answer (score 6):

```perl
s/\\'/\\\\'/g
```

---

All three of your patterns match a backslash followed by a quote, the above being the simplest.

Your testing was in vain because your string doesn't contain any backslashes. Both string literals `"\'this"` (from earlier edit) and `'\'this'` (from later edit) produce the string `'this`.

```perl
say "\'this";   # 'this
say '\'this';   # 'this
```

To produce the string `\'this`, you could use either of the following string literals (among others):

```perl
"\\'this"
```

```perl
'\\\'this'
```

```perl
say "\\'this";    # \'this
say '\\\'this';   # \'this
```

Comment: Sorry - I posted code that I had edited over and over again to test. I have edited the question now to show that this happens when you use '\'this' as well.

Comment: Same applies to `'\'this'`. `'\'this'` also produces `'this`. `'\\\'this'` would produce `\this`. I have updated the answer to match the update to the question.

Comment: You could also write it a bit differently to avoid it looking like a fence, e.g. `s/(\\')/\\$1/`

Comment: @Ecuador Captures add a speed penalty. Not sure how it compares to `s/(?=\\')/\\/`. (Subpatterns of lookaheads also add a speed penalty.)

Comment: @ikegami if this code is in a loop, doing thousands of replacements, you would be looking for speed agreed, but I would add the option for a single use statement to make the readability - I only mentioned it as an example. Your proposed lookahead is even better, and faster, I am getting 3.4m replacements/sec with the original, 2.7m/s with lookahead, 1.4m/s with capturing. I ran it on a VM with perl 5.24.

Comment: @Ecuador, Re "*if this code is in a loop, doing thousands of replacements,*", This is the case as often as it's not. /// Re "*but I would add the option for a single use statement to make the readability*",  I would *avoid* your code for reasons of readability. Replacing one short static string with another short static string is as simple as things can be. Adding captures, and interpolating backreferences complicates things.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, of course

```
s/[\\][']/\\\\'/g
```

This will match

```
\'this
```

And substitute with this

```
\\'this
```

This was the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: Re "*The answer is, of course `s/[\\][']/\\\\'/g`*", Not really. While that works, it's just a complicated way to write `s/\\'/\\\\'/g`. In any case, this doesn't answer the question since the OP says these two *didn't* work, and you didn't explain why it actually does work.

Comment: This is indeed a bad answer. Nobody should be writing `[\\][']` when they just mean `\\'`. That's not what the character class square brackets are for.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl**

Too much "regexing" in your snippet. Try:

```
my $line = '\'this';
$line =~ s/'/\\\\\'/g;
printf('%s',$line);
print "\n";

# \\'this
```

or... if you want another mode:

```
my $line = '\'this';
$line =~ s/'/\\'/g;
printf('%s',$line);
print "\n";

# \'this
```